# Rectangles are not drawn as expected

Tags: codenameone

Recently I was somewhat unsure about the presentation of my app and therefore I created a small tester app to look at this topic more closely.

For that I derived my own component class which did nothing els than draw the outer bounds of itself and was surprised that it wasn't completely shown - neither in the simulator, nor on my iPhone 5S.

Now to my question: Why is it that a component drawn as `aGraphics.drawRect(getX() + 2, getY() + 2, 10, 10)` shows as eleven pixels wide and high in the simulator and on my iPhone 5S?

[image: in simulator]     [image: on iPhone 5S full resolution closeup]

Here is some code which can be used to demonstrate this:

```
public class FormRectangleComponent extends Form {
    private class RectangleComponent extends Component {
        private int color;

        public RectangleComponent(int aColor) {
            color = aColor;
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics aGraphics) {
            aGraphics.setColor(color);
            aGraphics.drawRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
            Map<String,Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>() {{
                put("Display.displayWidth", Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth());
                put("rectangleComponent.x", getX());
                put("rectangleComponent.y", getY());
                put("rectangleComponent.width", getWidth());
                put("rectangleComponent.height", getHeight());
            }};
            aGraphics.setColor(0xffffff);
            aGraphics.drawRect(getX() + 2, getY() + 2, 10, 10);
            report(map);
        }

        @Override
        protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
            int side = Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight() / 10;
            return new Dimension(side, side);
        }
    }

    public FormRectangleComponent() {
        Display.getInstance().areMutableImagesFast();
        setTitle("FormRectangleComponent");
        setScrollable(false);
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        contentPane.setScrollableY(true);
        contentPane.getAllStyles().setBgPainter((Graphics aGraphics, Rectangle aRectangle) -> {
            aGraphics.setColor(0x00c0c0);
            aGraphics.fillRect(aRectangle.getX(), aRectangle.getY(), aRectangle.getWidth(), aRectangle.getHeight());
        });
        contentPane.add(new SpanLabel(
                "Below should be some frames showing all sides."));
        contentPane.add(new RectangleComponent(0xff0000));
        contentPane.add(new RectangleComponent(0x0000ff));
        contentPane.add(new RectangleComponent(0x00ff00));
    }

    private void report(Map<String, Object> map) {
        int maximumLength = 0;
        for (Entry<String, Object> entry: map.entrySet()) {
            maximumLength = Math.max(maximumLength, entry.getKey().length());
        }
        for (Entry<String, Object> entry: map.entrySet()) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int tally = 0; tally < (maximumLength - entry.getKey().length()); tally ++) {
                stringBuilder.append(' ');
            }
            stringBuilder
            .append(entry.getKey())
            .append(": ")
            .append(entry.getValue());
            Log.p(stringBuilder.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's [mentioned here](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Graphics.html#fillRect-int-int-int-int-) in brief but this behavior is based on the convention within the Java graphics API's documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html).

Graphics is a low level API and we tried to keep it consistent with the way Java works. All our samples rely on the width/height -1 convention so it's documented by example & consistency if by nothing else.

The logic for this is mathematical, you don't draw on pixels but in a virtual co-ordinate space that resides between the pixels which makes more sense as you start to transform graphics operations.

Comment: I have been working with Java for fivteen years and never noticed that. A better explanation is the pen analogy. Drawing a rectangle with no width still moves the pen which has a defined width. See [http://math.hws.edu/graphicsbook/c2/s5.html]